# Is there a way to use a specified type as a variable template type?

Tags: c++

I have a function that involves parameters which are the same type, I can use following code:

```
template<class... _Types>
void foo(_Types... args)
```

I wanna know if there are other ways to specify _Types be the type uint64_t?
Like this:

```
template<>
void foo(uint64_t... args)
```

Comment: `_Types` That name is reserved to the language implementation. By using it as a template parameter, the behaviour of your program will be undefined. You should use another name.

Comment: How about `std::initializer_list<uint64_t>`?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, It can be a way